# vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Property or method "$t" is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I am trying to implement vue-i18n [Vue-i18n Github](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) and I 'have got an error :

> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Property or method "$t" is not defined

My vuejs 2 app is working fine until I add the getting starded code, where am I wrong? Thanks in advance

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $t("message.hello")}}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.js"></script>

<script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      products: [
   'Boots',
  ]
   },
  })
</script>
<script>
 // Ready translated locale messages
 const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: 'hello world'
    }
  },
  ja: {
    message: {
      hello: 'こんにちは、世界'
    }
  }
  }

 // Create VueI18n instance with options
  const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'ja', // set locale
    messages, // set locale messages
  })

  // Create a Vue instance with `i18n` option
  new Vue({ i18n }).$mount('#app')
// Now the app has started!
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 instance of Vue, both mounting on #app? You can remove the first one and move your data to the one with the translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `i18n` in any Vue instance you want vue-i18n to work.

The first instance you have has no `i18n` specified.

Besides, you have two Vue instances, they don't work together, so what you probably need is just one (with `i18n` specified).

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $t("message.hello")}}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.js"></script>
<script>
  // Ready translated locale messages
  const messages = {
    en: {
      message: {
        hello: 'hello world'
      }
    },
    ja: {
      message: {
        hello: 'こんにちは、世界'
      }
    }
  }
  // Create VueI18n instance with options
  const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'ja', // set locale
    messages, // set locale messages
  })
  // Create a Vue instance with `i18n` option
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    i18n, // this is equivalent to `i18n: i18n,` (without quotes, naturally)
    data: {
      products: [
        'Boots',
      ]
    },
  })
  // Now the app has started!
</script>
```