# How to localize SFC Vue.js Component in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization, laravel-mix, vue-i18n

When I localize in SFC vue component

```
{{ $t('foo') }}
```

Then I recieved this error in the console, how can I call `$t` function

> Property or method "$t" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: please take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775725/vue-js597-vue-warn-property-or-method-t-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add packages required by localiztion

```
yarn add vue-i18n @kazupon/vue-i18n-loader
```

then add following config to `webpack.mix.js`, be sure `i18n()` should before `js()`

```
mix.extend( 'i18n', new class {
    webpackRules() {
        return [
            {
                resourceQuery: /blockType=i18n/,
                type:          'javascript/auto',
                loader:        '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader',
            },
        ];
    }
}(),
);

mix.i18n()
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

Add `resources/js/utils/i18n.js`, we will read config from `locale` directory

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('../locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

make directory `locales` and create file `resources/js/locales/en.json`, just add following content

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
}
```

now let us import i18n package in `resources/js/app.js`

```
import router from '@/router'
import i18n from '@/utils/i18n'

const el = "#app"
const app = new Vue({ i18n, router, el });
```

finally, you can use localization string in the Vue component file

```
{{ $t('foo') }}
```

You can define i18n rules in the vue file

```
<template>
  <button>{{ $t('Save') }}
</template>
<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "Save": "Save Now"
  }
}
</i18n>
```